# What does {{ annotation .ObjectMeta `abc` `def` }} mean in helm template

Tags: kubernetes-helm, istio

I'm new to helm. When I work with istio, I see something like `{{ annotation ...}}`  serveral times, more details:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: istio-proxy
  {{- if contains "/" (annotation .ObjectMeta `sidecar.istio.io/proxyImage` .Values.global.proxy.image) }}
    image: "{{ annotation .ObjectMeta `sidecar.istio.io/proxyImage` .Values.global.proxy.image }}"
  {{- else }}
    image: "{{ .ProxyImage }}"
  {{- end }}
```

You can find the above code from the [istio github](https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/f9dd346d845197bf4252877f26f4ddec74b85d4a/manifests/charts/istio-control/istio-discovery/files/grpc-agent.yaml#L49).

I have read the helm doc, so I think the `annotation` is a function, and all others (i.e. .ObjectMeta, sidecar.istio.io/proxyImage, .Values.global.proxy.image ) are just arguments. Am I right?

But I have no idea what the `annotation` function is. It would be better if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: That is Go `text/template` function-call syntax, but `annotation` is neither a [Helm-specific](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/main/pkg/engine/funcs.go) function nor a [Sprig](https://github.com/Masterminds/sprig/blob/master/functions.go) function.  Are you sure standard Helm processes this file, and the block you show isn't further quoted somehow?

Comment: @DavidMaze I have added the github link for your reference. And I can sure the helm chart can be processed.

Comment: That file isn't in the chart's `templates` directory, so Helm doesn't process it.  It's [included directly in a ConfigMap](https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/f9dd346d845197bf4252877f26f4ddec74b85d4a/manifests/charts/istio-control/istio-discovery/templates/istiod-injector-configmap.yaml#L61).  I'm not totally sure how it gets used from there.

Answer (score 0):

I just went hunting for the `annotation` template function in the Istio code and it's implemented by [getAnnotation](https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/066f4b429663f2cd7afce744b2a8bdde7d1103a9/pkg/kube/inject/template.go#L173-L179). The last argument to the function is a default value to use (presumably if the pod annotation doesn't exist).

As David Maze said in the comments above, the `annotation` function is not part of Helm. And the template in question is not actually a Helm template, but is an Istio template stored as a *static* file in the Helm chart. Its raw content is shoved into a ConfigMap without being processed by the Helm renderer (bringing the literal string `".Values.global.proxy.image"` into the ConfigMap as part of the data); e.g., see the [sidecar injector configmap](https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/7ced5e72445ee7062fe8b7c60fe50958f625be6d/manifests/charts/istio-control/istio-discovery/templates/istiod-injector-configmap.yaml#L60-L61). The Istio control-plane will then read this Istio template from the ConfigMap volume and render it with Go [text/template](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template), deserializing it into a struct with an `ObjectMeta` member, similar to:

```golang
type SidecarTemplateData struct {
    ...
    ObjectMeta     *metav1.ObjectMeta
    Spec           *corev1.PodSpec
    ...
}
```

^ `ObjectMeta` and `Spec` belong to the pod that is being injected with a sidecar.

If you now read the Istio template you pasted again, you'll see the `istio-proxy` container will run the image defined by a pod's `sidecar.istio.io/proxyImage` annotation, falling back to `.Values.global.proxy.image` if the annotation doesn't exist. But it will only do so if the returned value contains a slash (`/`), otherwise it will use the value of `.ProxyImage` for the sidecar image. Fun times.